# Unable to tap ‘search’ button on Android softKeyboard

Tags: android, selenium, automation, appium

I am trying to type in a search box within my app and tap/click on search button(magnifying glass) on keyboard. But I am unable to click/tap on it. I have tried below things:

```
driver.sendKeyEvent(84);
```

Appium says it successfully sent in the command but 'search' does not get tapped. Cursor remains in text box and results do not filter.

```
HashMap swipeObject = new HashMap();
swipeObject.put("keycode", 84);
((JavascriptExecutor ) driver).executeScript("mobile: keyevent", swipeObject);
```

Appium says not yet implemented.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver1; jse.executeScript("UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().keyboard().buttons()['Done'].tap();");
```

Appium says not yet implemented.

```
driver.sendKeyEvent(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER, AndroidKeyMetastate.META_FUNCTION_ON);
```

Appium says it successfully sent in the command but 'search' does not get tapped. Cursor remains in text box and results do not filter.

```
driver.sendKeyEvent(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER);
```

Nothing happens

All other send key events works except ENTER, Search. I can use sendKeyEvent for alphabets, numbers, space etc.

I am using Ecllipse, AndroidDriver, AppiumDriver, TestNG, Appium(1.2.4.1), Samsung Galaxy Note 3.

Any help on this would be really helpful. I went through lot of Googling but till not successful tapping search key.